# InfluxDB API token concept

Tags: token, access-token, influxdb

I am using InfluxDB OSS v2 for a small project, but did not quite understand how API tokens and users should be used.

## Goal

Having a setup that follows the least privilege principle. This should include that

- only the boss of the database instance can add/delete organizations and add/delete users,
- only the admin of the organization1 and maybe the boss of the DB instance can add/delete buckets to organization1
- all users belonging to organization1 can write to and read from buckets they are allowed to:

  - engineerA can write to and read from all buckets within organization1
  - engineerB can write to and read from bucket1 and bucket3 of organization1

The database is going to be used mainly with HTTP requests.

## What I understood and did so far

It is obviously important to do proper access rights management.
After setting up the influxDB instance, I was asked to create an initial user that owns the operator token. This user should only serve as database boss which is used to create/delete database users and add/delete organizations. The operator token should not be known to anybody not allowed to apply the mentioned changes.
An initial organization "organization1" was created. The user owning the operator token removed himself from organization1 (is that needed?).
Then, using the operator token, I made 3 new users:

- Organization1_admin
- Organization1_engineerA
- Organization1_engineerB

As I see on the UI, at this point, the 3 new users are part of the organization1. I created the organization1_admin with the --owner flag. So, that user now is the owner of organization1 while the other 2 users have the "member" role.

## What still needs to be done

Of what I read in the docs of influxDB, all-access tokens and customized tokens should now be created for least privilegem authentication.
I have not quite understood how users and tokens are related. Can anyone explain a bit?

Also, every user can once logged in generate API tokens (if the privileges allow it). Can tokens generated by for example organization1_admin only be used by that same?